# How to count number of values within specific date interval from pandas dataframe values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count and plot the number of 'payout' values by day for period 2018-04-01 to 2018-05-01 from this dataframe:

```
df['payout'].head(10)

0   2017-02-14 11:00:06
1   2015-03-14 11:00:06
2   2014-04-14 11:00:06
3   2017-11-14 11:00:06
4   2016-12-14 11:00:06
5   2018-04-10 11:00:06
6   2018-04-11 11:00:06
7   2018-04-12 11:00:06
8   2018-04-13 11:00:06
9   2018-04-14 11:00:06
```

I could obtain day-to-plot for the year 2018:

```
(df.loc[df['payout'].dt.year.between(2018, 2019), 'payout']
         .dt.to_period('D')
         .value_counts()
         .sort_index()
         .plot(kind="bar")
)
```

[image]

How do I shrink the plot to April 2018 only?

Thanks

Comment: not sure what your dataframe looks like and what you're trying to do. But if the times are in the index (perhaps you can put them there), Pandas supports indexing with date strings like so: `df.loc['2018-04-01':'2018-04-30']`

Comment: The dataframe is in the question, as well as the description of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same logic you were using, but use the datestrings you are interested in:

```
(df.loc[df['payout'].between('2018-04-01', '2018-04-30'), 'payout']
         .dt.to_period('D')
         .value_counts()
         .sort_index()
         .plot(kind="bar")
)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get reed of the of number of excessive x ticks labels, how do I get, for example, every five ticks put a label? Thank you @sacul

Comment: @user40, you're welcome, glad I could help :) The tick label problem is a separate issue, please ask a new question

Answer (score 3):

Just check both month and year and use your current method

```
df.loc[(df.date.dt.month == 4) & (df.date.dt.year == 2018), 'payout']
```

Answer (score 1):

an other solution :

```
df[(df['date'] >= '2018-04-01') & (df['date'] < '2018-05-01')]['payout']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.set_index('payout').loc['2018-04-01':'2018-04-30']
```

for your first line should do it.

- `.set_index` makes your payout column the index. This does not modify the original `df`. See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for details.
- Now that you have a `DatetimeIndex`, you can just use `.loc` to index with date strings directly. Note that unlike normal indexing, this will include all 24 hours of April 30.