# How to plot aggregated by date pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have this dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["2017-01-14",1],
    ["2017-01-14",30],
    ["2017-01-16",216],
    ["2017-02-17",23],
    ["2017-02-17",2],
    ["2017-03-19",745],
    ["2017-03-19",32],
    ["2017-03-20",11],
    ["2017-03-20",222],
    ["2017-03-21",4]],columns=["date","payout_value"])
```

To aggregate `payout_value` by date I use:

```
df_daily=df.groupby('date').agg(['sum'])

payout_value
sum
date    
2017-01-14  31
2017-01-16  216
2017-02-17  25
2017-03-19  777
2017-03-20  233
2017-03-21  4
```

How do I plot (bar chart) dates on x-axis and aggregated payout sum on y axis?

I tried using `df.plot(x='date', y='payout_value',kind="bar")` approach, but there is no 'date' column in `df_daily` dataframe, `print(list(df_daily))` gives `[('payout_value', 'sum')]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count number of values within specific date interval from pandas dataframe values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593341/how-to-count-number-of-values-within-specific-date-interval-from-pandas-datafram)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you are almost there,
    use `reset_index` and plot your by df_daily

```
df_daily=df.groupby('date').agg(['sum']).reset_index()
df_daily.plot(x='date', y='payout_value',kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.groupby('date').agg(['sum']).plot.bar(legend='')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('payout value sum')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can `set_index` and `sum`

```
df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)).set_index('date').payout_value.sum(level=0).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I can code is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([["2017-01-14",1],
    ["2017-01-14",30],
    ["2017-01-16",216],
    ["2017-02-17",23],
    ["2017-02-17",2],
    ["2017-03-19",745],
    ["2017-03-19",32],
    ["2017-03-20",11],
    ["2017-03-20",222],
    ["2017-03-21",4]], columns=["date","payout_value"])

df.groupby('date').agg('sum').plot(kind='bar', y='payout_value')
plt.show()
```

[image: link to the bar plot]