# How to aggregate and plot data from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have this dataframe

```
df[['payout_date','total_value']].head(10)

    payout_date         total_value
0   2017-02-14T11:00:06  177.313
1   2017-02-14T11:00:06  0.000
2   2017-02-01T00:00:00  0.000
3   2017-02-14T11:00:06  47.392
4   2017-02-14T11:00:06  16.254
5   2017-02-14T11:00:06  125.818
6   2017-02-14T11:00:06  0.000
7   2017-02-14T11:00:06  0.000
8   2017-02-14T11:00:06  0.000
9   2017-02-14T11:00:06  0.000
```

I am using this code to plot the aggregated sum of `total_value` within specific date-range by day (and by month), but it plots a bar for each `total_value` and doesn't sum-aggregate `total_value` by day.

```
(df.set_index('payout_date')
                    .loc['2018-02-01':'2018-02-02']
                    .groupby('payout_date')
                    .agg(['sum'])
                    .reset_index()
                    .plot(x='payout_date', y='total_value',kind="bar"))
plt.show()
```

Data is not aggregated, I get bar for each value from df:

[image]

How to aggregate `total_value` by date and by month?

I tried to use answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594613/how-to-plot-aggregated-by-date-pandas-dataframe) and couple other similar questions but none of them worked for the date format that is used here.

I also tried adding `.dt.to_period('M')` to the code but I get `TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot` error.

Comment: what happens if you remove .loc['2018-02-01':'2018-02-02']?

Comment: @Joe I tried that, it calculates for extremely long time (>30min and I stop the script), because the dataframe is very big, so I have to chose a specific interval.

Comment: with few rows, it plots correctly the aggregate without .loc Try as well, if it works, make the selection before the code you posted

Comment: @Joe I did new_df=df.set_index('payout_date').loc['2018-02-01':'2018-02-02'] and then tried to use the initial code without .loc but I am getting 'KeyError: 'payout_date'' error, so there is not 'payout_date' column in new_df? Why? How do I make the selection properly before the original code? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'payout_date': {0: '2017-02-01T11:00:06',   1: '2017-02-01T11:00:06',   2: '2017-02-02T00:00:00',   3: '2017-02-14T11:00:06',   4: '2017-02-14T11:00:06',   5: '2017-02-15T11:00:06',   6: '2017-02-15T11:00:06',   7: '2017-02-16T11:00:06',   8: '2017-02-16T11:00:06',   9: '2017-02-16T11:00:06'},  'total_value':{0: 177.313,   1: 22.0,   2: 25.0,   3: 47.391999999999996,   4: 16.254,   5: 125.818,   6: 85.0,   7: 42.0,8: 22.0,   9: 19.0}})
```

Use **`normalize`** to just group by day:

```
df.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.payout_date).normalize()).sum().reset_index()

  payout_date  total_value
0  2017-02-01      199.313
1  2017-02-02       48.000
2  2017-02-14       63.646
3  2017-02-15      210.818
4  2017-02-16       83.000
```

Extend the previous command to plot:

```
df.groupby(
    pd.DatetimeIndex(df.payout_date)      \
    .normalize().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))    \
    .agg(['sum'])                         \
    .reset_index()                        \
    .plot(x='index', y='total_value', kind='bar')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output for my sample data:

[image]

If you want to apply this on a subset, you can do something like the following:

```
tmp = df.loc[(df.payout_date > '2017-02-01') & (df.payout_date < '2017-02-15')]

tmp.groupby(
    pd.DatetimeIndex(tmp.payout_date)                     \
    .normalize().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['total_value']     \
    .agg(['sum'])

# Result
                sum
2017-02-01  199.313
2017-02-02   25.000
2017-02-14   63.646
```

Which will only sum your desired range.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
df = df.iloc[1:7]
(df.set_index('payout_date')
                .groupby('payout_date')
                .agg(['sum'])
                .reset_index()
                .plot(x='payout_date', y='total_value',kind="bar"))
plt.show()
```

Where the index are selected before

Comment: I got very strange result. What does 'index are selected before' means? How do I select the index? Also, what df.iloc[1:7] stands for? What it's purpose?

Comment: @user40 With `df = df.iloc[1:7]` you select the rows. in this case from the row 1 to 7. If for example you want the first 1000 rows change to `df.iloc[0:1000]`