# Trim, Aggregate and Plot From Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My problem is similar to the question asked [How to aggregate and plot data from pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612340/how-to-aggregate-and-plot-data-from-pandas-dataframe)

Except that my data is less than perfect.

I have a DataFrame with the data read in from a CSV file with the following format:

```
total_value;payout_date  
25;2021-02-24-09-AM
10;2021-02-24-09-PM
16;2021-02-24-10-AM
2;2021-02-24-10-PM
12;2021-02-24-11-AM
6;2021-02-24-11-PM
27;2021-02-24-12-PM
3;2021-02-25-01-AM
20;2021-02-25-01-PM
16;2021-02-26-10-AM
1;2021-02-26-10-PM
17;2021-02-26-11-AM
2;2021-02-26-11-PM
4;2021-02-26-12-AM
17;2021-02-26-12-PM
4;2021-02-27-01-AM
5;2021-02-27-01-PM
6;2021-02-27-02-AM
```

The datetime format is `yyyy-mm-dd-h12-am`. How can I trim the date to just `yyyy-mm-dd` before I can aggregate the totals. For example,

```
4;2021-02-27-01-AM
5;2021-02-27-01-PM
6;2021-02-27-02-AM
```

becomes

```
4;2021-02-27
5;2021-02-27
6;2021-02-27
```

and the expected result is

```
15;2021-02-27
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the last 6 characters off, convert it to date-time and then groupby & sum:

```
df.payout_date = df.payout_date.str[:-6]

df.payout_date = pd.to_datetime(df.payout_date)

result = df.groupby(df.payout_date).sum()
```

to get

```
>>> result

             total_value
payout_date
2021-02-24            98
2021-02-25            23
2021-02-26            57
2021-02-27            15
```

with `result.plot` giving

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mustafa. Great job! That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I am trying to vote up +1 but I am getting this message "Don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking its check mark." How can I mark the answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: @absolutelynewbie glad to be of help!  There is a check mark under the vote buttons, you can click that; for the visual, please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774. Thanks!